# Scheme Traverse and print a DAG in a depth first way

Tags: printing, functional-programming, scheme, racket, tree-traversal

Let a **NODE** be a function with a **STORE** in its closure. All leafs of the graph have a STORE that is a single value (either a constant or a variable) and all internal nodes have a STORE that is a list containing:

1. A symbol representing a function ('+ '* 'cos 'sin etc)
2. A list of one or more NODES representing the children of this NODE.
3. A simplification function (which is irrelevant for my question).

Assume *[[(NODE f)]] = [[(f STORE)]]* if f is a procedure and STORE is the STORE in NODE'S closure.

I am trying to find a way to traverse this tree and **print an expression that can be evaluated with (eval)**. I have come close but I just cannot get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
(define repr
  (lambda(store)
    (if (is_leaf? store)
        store
        (list (car store)
              (repr_helper (cadr store) repr)))))

(define repr_helper
  (lambda(f_list arg)
    (cond ((null? f_list) '())
          (else (cons ((car f_list) arg) (repr_helper (cdr f_list) arg))))))
```

Simple exemple: Assume a tree with a single addition of 4 arguments (creates a + node with 4 children all of which are leaves).

```
((Add 10 'x 'y 'z) repr)
```

**Output:** '(+ (10 x y z)).

**Expected output:** '(+ 10 x y z)

As you can see the problem comes from the extra parenthesis inside the expression. You can imagine this is even worse for more complex examples. I understand where I create the list and why the parenthesis is there, but I can't seem to find a way to remove it, print the values correctly.

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem. How are you calling `repr`? Please post all the missing information: the `is_leaf?` procedure, the `store` object that produces the wrong output, and all the other procedures so that we can execute the code. What's expected from a good question is that anyone can copy, paste and execute the code in the question and receive the same error that you report.

Comment: The code is a bit long, so I thought posting all of it is a bad idea. I will try to make a minimal example, but simply a way to print the contents of a list would be enough as an answer for me. @ÓscarLópez

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to answer your question. I'll attempt to _guess_, but that's as far as anyone can help, without a proper _working_ minimal example. Try replacing the last 2 lines in `repr` with this: `(append (list (car store)) (repr_helper (cadr store) repr))`. If that doesn't work, then good luck.

Comment: I was about to paste out the code, but this actually works. I will try and decode it, but from appearances it seems to append the list created by the helper to the original one. Getting the order correctly also. I feel kind of stupid for not thinking about that. You are most welcome to type that into an answer I will accept. Thanks!! @ÓscarLópez

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Lucky guess :)

Comment: my bad, there was a simpler and more obvious way to solve your question, I updated my answer.

Comment: This seems somewhat more efficient and works just as good, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the part that builds the list, like this:

```
(define repr
  (lambda (store)
    (if (is_leaf? store)
        store
        (cons (car store)
              (repr_helper (cadr store) repr)))))
```

We just need to add a new item at the head of the list returned by `repr_helper`, a call to `cons` will do the trick.